# System of parameters which have linear independent images in the cotangent space

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Given a Noetherian, local ring $(R,m)$, can we always find a system of parameters whose images in the cotangent space $m/m^2$ are linearly independent?

We can do this in the regular case, by just choosing a basis for the cotangent space and looking at their preimages in $m$ under the canonical map. By Nakayama's lemma these generate $m$ and hence form a system of parameters. Can we do this for any general Noetherian, local ring?

Comment: A minimal set of generators for $\mathfrak{m}$ should do it. If they were linearly dependent in $\mathfrak{m}/\mathfrak{m}^2$, then a smaller subset would suffice to generate $\mathfrak{m}$ by Nakayama.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By induction let's just worry about picking one parameter element $x$. We need $x$ to be in $m$, but  outside all the minimal primes of $R$ and $m^2$. This smells exactly like [Prime Avoidance](http://commalg.wiki-site.com/index.php/Prime_avoidance_lemma) (note that they don't have to be all primes!). Now replace $R$ by $R/(x)$ and repeat.